# How to use copy files with Windows Xcopy cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to copy files from folder1 to folder2 but exclude few files. lets say 
Source dir: D:\test1 
Dest dir: D:\test2

Source dir has files: hello1.txt, hello2.txt, hello3.pdf.....(and so on with different extension)

My batch cmd: Xcopy /Y /exclude:D:\test1\Excludefiles.txt D:\test1 D:\test2

I have added list of files in Excludefiles.txt that I dont want to copy.

The issue is everything works fine except Excludefiles.txt gets copied in dest folder too which I dont want. How can I exclude Excludefiles.txt getting copied?

Comment: By putting it in the text file.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I have added it in text file and it works fine (all the listed files does not gets copied). But the text file itself (in my case Exclude.txt) gets copied to in dest folder.

Comment: I think you misunderstood @Mark. Include the file `Excludefiles.txt` to the list of files inside `Excludefules.txt`. IOW, edit `Excludefiles.txt` and add `Excludefiles.txt` in that file and then save it.

Comment: @KenWhite I am sorry but I still dont get it. Excludefiles.txt is in my source folder, I added file name that I dont want to copy in Excludefiles.txt and saved it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add the filename `Excludefiles.txt` to the list of the files to exclude. Add `Excludefiles.txt` inside `Excludefiles.txt` using Notepad to edit `Excludefiles.txt`. In other words, if the contents of `Excludefiles.txt` currently is `File1.txt`, `File2.txt`, edit it to contain `File1.txt`, `File2.txt`, `Excludefiles.txt` instead. I don't know how to explain it any more clearly than that, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah I See. Okay thanks.